# How to track failed/expired azure event grid delivery message?

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

Good to see that azure event grid has a 24 hour retry policy with exponential back off for event delivery with 99.99% availability. However, I have an encountered a scenario where one of event grid message expected didn't reach even after 24 hours.

I have a web hook configured for the event with subject /subscriptions/id/resourcegroups/name/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/name which I expect after resource group deployment completes, which it did successfully as I see from azure portal.

Could you help clarify the questions below,

1. To check if 24 h retry was attempted, where can I find the logs
2. If attempted and retries exhausted, where can I find the logs
3. If delivery didn't happen even if the consumer was available due to a failure or unavailability of event grid, where can I find the logs

Comment: In the future EventGrid will have a dead-letter queue. At the moment, don't think any of the information you're looking for is available. Azure Monitor most likely will provide metrics you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @SeanFeldman. Metrics cover some of the scenarios yes, but couldn't get anything more than numbers. Just noticed something close to this in the pipeline, https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909934-azure-event-grid/suggestions/33360442-capture-failed-delivery-to-subscriber

Comment: The feature of the deadletterdestination in the subscription has been release, still in the preview, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like it is mentioned in the Sean's comment this support is coming soon.

Based on the *Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid*, Version=2.0.0.0 we can expected a new property such as **deadletterdestination** in the event subscription, see the following payload snippet of the sample for creatingOrUpdating subscription:

```
    {
      "properties": {
        "deadletterdestination": {
          "endpointType": "StorageBlob",
          "properties": {
            "blobContainerName": "{myContainerName}",
            "resourceId": "/subscriptions/{mySubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{myResourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{myStorageAccount}"
          }
        },
        "destination": {
          "endpointType": "WebHook",
          "properties": {
          "endpointUrl": "{myEndpointUrl}"
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "isSubjectCaseSensitive": false,
          "subjectBeginsWith": null,
          "subjectEndsWith": null
        },
        "labels": ["xxx"],
        "eventDeliverySchema": "InputEventSchema",
        "retryPolicy": {
         "maxDeliveryAttempts": 30,
         "eventTimeToLiveInMinutes": 1440
        }
      }
    }
```

When you put a REST request (api-version=2018-05-01-preview) for creating an event subscription with the above payload, the response is failed with the following message:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "code": "InvalidRequest",
        "message": "DeadLettering is currently not enabled in the service and support for it is coming soon. Until then, please re-issue the event subscription creation/update request without setting a deadletter destination."
    }
  }
```

I am looking forward for this great feature, where each subscription can be a source of the event for deadlettering and I hope there will be more endpointTypes for deadletterdestination such as EventHub, StorageQueue, ServiceBus, WebHook, etc.

**Update:**

Thanks for azure event grid team for releasing preview of the  *deadletterdestination* feature. Now, each subscription can decided when the deadletter can be sent. Today we can sent it to the storage blob.

The following screen snippet shows the deadletter stored in the blob storage:

[image]

See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/manage-event-delivery).